# Composition in Stoch Category defined by Lawrence.

Tags: probability-theory, category-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{F}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{F}_Y)$ be meausurables spaces. A probabilistic function  ${T}:{(X,\mathcal{F}_X)}\rightarrow{(Y,\mathcal{F}_Y)}$ is a function
$$
    {T}:{X\times \mathcal{F}_Y}\rightarrow{[0,1]}, 
$$
such that

- For all $x\in X$, the function ${T_x:=T(x,\cdot)}:{\mathcal{F}_Y}\rightarrow{[0,1]}$ is a probability measure defined in $(Y,\mathcal{F}_Y)$.
- For all $F_Y\in\mathcal{F}_Y$, the function ${T_{F_Y}:= T(\cdot,F_Y)}:{X}\rightarrow{[0,1]}$ is $\mathcal{F}_X/\mathcal{B}([0,1])-$meausurable.

The composition for two probabilistic functions ${U\circ T}:{(X,\mathcal{F}_X)}\rightarrow{(Z,\mathcal{F}_Z)}$ is given by:
$$U\circ T (x,\mathcal{F}_Z) = \int_Y U(\cdot,F_Z) \,d T_x = \int_{y\in Y} U(y,F_Z) \, T(x,dy),  $$
for all $x\in X$ and $F_Z\in \mathcal{F}_Z$.

In https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/lawvereprobability1962.pdf it is established that:
$$  V\circ(U\circ T)= (V\circ U)\circ T  $$
for ${T}:{(X,\mathcal{F}_X)}\rightarrow{(Y,\mathcal{F}_Y)}$, ${U}:{(Y,\mathcal{F}_Y)}\rightarrow{(Z,\mathcal{F}_Z)}$ and ${V}:{(Z,\mathcal{F}_Z)}\rightarrow{(W,\mathcal{F}_W)}$ probabilistic function.

I have trouble proving this identity.

It must be proved that $V \circ (U \circ T) (x, F_W) = (V \circ U) \circ T (x, F_W).  $

On the one hand, we have

\begin{align}\label{eqn:stochcat_01}
    (V\circ U)\circ T (x,F_W)
    & = \int_Y V\circ U(\cdot,F_W) \, d T_x, \notag \\
    & = \int_Y \left( \int_Z V(\cdot,F_W) \, d U_y \right) \, dT_x
\end{align}

On the other hand, we have $$V\circ (U\circ T) (x,F_W) = \int_Z V(\cdot,F_W) \, d( U\circ T)_x,$$

where $ U\circ T (x,\mathcal{F}_Z) = \int_Y U(\cdot,F_Z) \,d T_x = \int_{y\in Y} U(y,F_Z) \, T(x,dy)$.

My questions is:
Who looks like $d( U\circ T)_x?$